# connect mysql database in cpanel server in local running laravel application

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pos

I have developed POS using the laravel framework. I want to connect my hosted account MySQL database local running laravel application. please help me to way to save data in cpanel MySQL server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable mysql remote access in your cpanel.

> Log into cPanel. Click the Remote MySQL button in the Databases
>   section. Enter the remote IP address in the Add Access Host section.
>   Click the Add Host button. You will then see a message stating the
>   host IP address was added to the access list.

For more with images i have found https://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/databases/setting-up-a-remote-mysql-connection-in-cpanel

Sorry i cant write as comment because of rep.

Comment: This Part i have done. I want to connect with laravel application with that remote mysql database. I have try but it will show access denied.